# Functional Programming exercise (Lambda function)

Tags: java, function, lambda, functional-programming

Happy new year everyone!

I have the following exercise for my Programming courses:

Write a class named Imbauba. Class must contain the following method:

A public method named dit which has a parameter (Function Float, Float type) named dawnward and returns Fuction Float, Float result. Lambda function which is returned must contain the value of dawnward divided by 67

```
   public class Imbauba {
        public Function<Float, Float> dit(Function<Float, Float> dawnward) {
             Function<Float, Float> sss = (a) -> dawnward / 67F;
             return sss;
        }
   }
```

This is what I've done so far. I have no clue how to continue. Can anyone guide me close to the solution?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the method on the `Function`. There is no funky syntaz to call the "function" of a *functional interface*. Something like:

```
         Function<Float, Float> sss = (a) -> dawnward.apply(a) / 67F;
```

@VLAZ mentions `andThen` in the comments. `compose` does the same thing in the opposite order. I think they are detrimental to readability, and are only really useful if it avoids creating another lambda expression (and even then I'd prefer not to bother).

Comment: Just for reference - the `Function` class also has a method called [`andThen`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Function.html#andThen-java.util.function.Function-) that will perform functional composition with another `Function`. The equivalent to the above would be `Function<Float, Float> sss = dawnward.andThen(x -> x / 67F);`

Comment: Just curious why do you think that `return dawnward.andThen(x -> x / 67F)` is *detrimental to readability* and `return (a) -> dawnward.apply(a) / 67F`  is not?

Comment: @Naman It introduces another method. I can never remember which way around those methods work. Far too much extra thinking for me. OTOH, `andThen` does reduce the size of the lambda and assists in factoring it out.